# Trying to use Vorta to back up to Seagate external hard drive and getting "Unable to add your repository" message

Tags: backup

Not sure what is amiss here, and I've not been able to find anyone writing about this problem. My Seagate Backup Plus Slim worked fine for Timeshift backups as recently as a few minutes ago. Was following these instructions: https://vorta.borgbase.com/usage/local/
On Vorta's "Intialize New Backup Repository" screen, I chose the Seagate HD as the local repository, entered and confirmed password, clicked "Add", and got the, "Unable to add your repository" message. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: did you read [this Github post])https://github.com/borgbase/vorta/discussions/796) about the same issue with a response from the maintainer? Perhaps resurrect the topic there?